# Magento2 - Rest API - Add product to cart with "customizable option" of type "checkbox"

Tags: rest, magento2

I have problems with adding products to the cart by REST Api, if the product has custom options and the option is of the "checkbox" type.
I tried as below, but then only one "checkbox" is added, not two.

```
{
    "item_id": 111
    "sku": "sku",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "price": 159,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "1111",
    "product_option": {
        "extension_attributes": {
            "custom_options": [
                {
                    "option_id": 1,
                    "option_value": 1
                },
                {
                    "option_id": 1,
                    "option_value": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
{
    "item_id": 111
    "sku": "sku",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "price": 159,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "1111",
    "product_option": {
        "extension_attributes": {
            "custom_options": [
                {
                    "option_id": 1,
                    "option_value": [1,2]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But the above produces validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use cartId. Before adding a product to the cart, I create it using API route POST /V1/guest-carts. After that, I get cartId from the response and use it for all requests to cart endpoints. So it's not a solution.

Also when I try to add a product with a customizable option radio everything works